# How to check the version of Meteor.js on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I installed Meteor for Windows and want to know what version of Meteor I have installed to decide if its time to update. How can this be done?

`meteor update` does not work on Windows yet.

`meteor --version` returns the message `Unreleased (running from a checkout)`

Comment: I believe you're seeing 'Unreleased' because of Meteorite. If you remove the Meteor object from smart.json and smart.lock, you should be able to see the current version.

Comment: Are you able to look at file metadata?  There might be a version number buried in there somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you installed the Windows version via the MSI, you can look in the standard windows add/remove programs wizard to see what version you have.

The version of Meteor for Windows you are using does not use the 'warehouse' and therefore Meteor always uses a version of 'none'.
There is an experimental version of Meteor for Windows which does use the warehouse available at: https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor/wiki/Windows

Answer (score 11):

In the project folder, in command line try this...

```
meteor --version
```

Comment: Thats interesting to know!

Answer (score 3):

cd into your hidden .meteor folder and open up the release file inside the folder, it will have the version number

$ cd .meteor

$ nano release

Comment: The contents inside the release file is `none`

Comment: yeah I guess it doesn't work on checkouts, happened to me also

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the Meteor CLI, `meteor show meteor` has interesting output. This is what I got:

```
$ meteor show meteor
Package: meteor@1.1.10                        
Maintainers: mdg                              
Exports: Meteor                               

This is an internal Meteor package.           

Recent versions:                              
  1.1.5   March 18th, 2015                    
  1.1.6   April 1st, 2015
  1.1.7   September 22nd, 2015
  1.1.9   September 29th, 2015
  1.1.10  October 27th, 2015    installed

Older and pre-release versions of meteor have been hidden. To see all 73 versions, run 'meteor show --show-all meteor'.
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you can always check this in the browser with `Meteor.release` command put in devtools console of your Meteor app page.